# "I am looking for someone settled" - what does it mean?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I sent my CV to someone for a job and he replied something like this.

> "You have a good CV. I'm looking for someone settled...."

What does it mean? Is he looking for someone for the position or does it imply something else?

Comment: At a guess, he is looking for someone who is unlikely to change jobs any time soon. Do you have a wife, mortgage and kids? Just kidding!

Comment: To me it might indicate that they're looking for someone who is a) already working for that company or that b) you are in some way not settled. Can you give use some more context as to why he might think that?

Comment: You don't say whether the submission of your CV was speculative or in response to a job vacancy you had heard about. You also don't say whether the comment about 'settled' was positive or negative in terms of your CV, or whether you had a job offer. If the comment was negative I would have expected it to have been preceded by 'but' or 'however' to make a contrast with the employer's first positve comment.

Answer (score 1):

In the context given (job interview, CV response), settle will in all likelihood speak towards the personal status of an individual; e.g. married vs. unmarried, children vs. no children and so on.

Looking for somebody settled, means they are looking somebody who are at a stage in their life where they'll be considered stable, and not likely to move on soon.

This dictionary definition would cover that interpretation:

Definition of **[settle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/settle)**

> b :  to take up an ordered or stable life —often used with *down* [marry
>   and settle down]

Comment: I will say in this context the settle means "slave" who is married and carrying responsibilities of family being patron of the family.

Answer (score 0):

They are looking for someone who will stay in they job for a while as opposed to a less "settled" individual who may wish to change jobs/city/country frequently

Comment: I agree with you here but can you add some evidence that would show that this is the intended meaning, for at the moment there could be many possibilities.

Comment: Reading between the lines of a CV I haven't seen and second-guessing the prospective employer's reply, it may be that the OP has had a succession of jobs, one after the other. If that's the case then the reply is informing the OP that his/her lack of continuity in working for one employer indicates an "unsettled" career path to date.